# Change nuget package location in Linqpad

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, linqpad

I am trying to install the Active Directory Authentication Library in Linqpad Nuget manager and I am getting the path/location too long message:

[image]

I have attempted to change the install location by adding a setting for repository path to the LinqPad.nuget.config, which now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\Ng" />
      </config>
</configuration>
```

However, the packages are still being installed in the user/appdata folder.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can now, from version v5.06.05 (in beta at time of writing).

Go to LINQPad's NuGet package manager and click **Settings**, then **Advanced**.

Comment: In Linqpad 6  in NuGet package manager -> Settings -> Advanced there is only "Proxy Settings ..." available. I cannot find anything to set the path for local packages.

Answer (score 1):

In 2021 and with Linqpad 6 you can change the path for local packages by adding a system variable "NUGET_PACKAGES" with value set to whatever path you like.

Comment: That's right - LINQPad 6 uses the standard NuGet global packages folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my LINQPad 5 (v5.44.02).
All the Nuget packages you download from LINQPad will be saved/stored in some folder on your computer. By default, these packages will be saved in the %LocalAppData%\LINQPad\NuGet.FW46 folder.

[NuGet Settings -> Advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFqWb.png)

If you happen to have a long username then sometimes the file path of the package you are going to download will exceed the maximum limit.

I was able to fix this issue by updating this folder to a location something like "E:LP_Nuget". This actually reduced the file path length, and I was succesfully able to download the packages. With this change, all your LINQPad NuGet package will now be downloaded to this new folder.

Open LINQPad NuGet Manager
Ctrl + Shift + P

Click on the "Settings" button at the bottom left corner.

Select the "Advanced" tab and you should be able to see/change the NuGet package folder location.

Update this to a folder which has short file path. For instance, something like "C:\LINQPad_Packages".